# How to set a redirect after sign in URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

my rails 3 app is working with omniauth to allow for FB Connect signin/registering...

I want to have to set some type of session url that can be called when appropriate to redirect after signin.

I can't use the devise method as the redirect url needs to be sent to a JS dialog that does opener.window.location.path...

What's the best way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send to the JS Dailog one way to do in rails is set and instance varaible(@test_path).In the view under Event.Observe(dom:load) set the property set in pervious instance variable to opener.window.location.path

Something like this

```
Event.observe(document, "dom:loaded", function(e){
opener.window.location.path = <%= @test_path %>
});
```